# Laravel + Tabulator pagination not working? ajaxURL used by Tabulator looks ok and URL works as expected

Tags: laravel, tabulator

Looking at the documentation of Tabulator:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/page
It mentions:

> If you are a Laravel user then you should find that the auto generated
>   URL's and data processing work straight out the box with no additional
>   configuration needed.

However, I get a "loading" message in the table (which stays there), and no data is shown.
According to devtools, the data seems to get loaded correctly from Laravel (v6).

Using example similar to the one mentioned in the Tabulator documentation:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    pagination:"remote", //enable remote pagination
    ajaxURL:"http://testdata.com/data", //set url for ajax request
    paginationSize:5, //optional parameter to request a certain number of rows per page
});
```

In Chrome devtools I see the correct request being made (with a successful 200 result):

```
http://testdata.com/data?page=1&size=5
```

When I manually open that URL (or in devtools) I see the correct paginated data (note: my Laravel pagination is set to 30 items per page).

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": Array[30][
...
  ],
  "first_page_url": "http://testdata.com/data?page=1",
  "from": 1,
  "last_page": 41,
  "last_page_url": "http://testdata.com/data?page=41",
  "next_page_url": "http://testdata.com/data?page=2",
  "path": "http://testdata.com/data",
  "per_page": 30,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 30,
  "total": 1209
}
```

Tried both `->paginate(30)` and `->simplePaginate(30)` in Laravel.
Alternatively, when I use a route + controller to push the data to the view, and show that as local data, then Tabulator shows the data just fine.

Suggestions?

**update**: this seems to be related to [Blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade). When I use Tabulator in an `@extends` environment I get the above behavior. When using in plain HTML page it works as expected. Will investigate why `@extends` is causing issues.

Comment: can you use the advanced ajax method and console log the response data `ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){ console.log(response.tableData); }`

Comment: it does return `response.data`, not `response.tableData` (which I believe is correct, based on the documentation). The full `response` looks like the example I provided. Also tried to add `paginationDataReceived:{"data": "tableData"}`, but no result.

Comment: update: this seems to be related to Blade templates. When I use Tabulator in an `@extends` environment I get the above behavior. When using in plain HTML page it works as expected. Will investigate why `@extends` is causing issues.